# ComException -2147467259 Arcgis 10 VB.net +Geoprocessing

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, geoprocessing, arcgis-engine

I have a problem when i execute GeoProcessing in ArcEngine 10 with VB.net

1. i had create the toolbox : Models.tbx
2. and  Model Process : disolveRoute with 2 parameters

[image]

My Function is :

```
 Sub diso()
    Dim dissolveTable As ITable = CType(featureLayerRoute, ITable)
    ' Create geoprocessor. Overwrite true will replace existing output.
    Dim gp As IGeoProcessor2 = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessor()
    Dim trac As ITrackCancel = New CancelTracker
    Dim Result As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2
    Dim parameters As IVariantArray = New VarArrayClass()
    gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", "Database Connections\IFE connexion.sde")
    gp.OverwriteOutput = True
    gp.AddToolbox("data\Models.tbx")
    parameters.Add(dissolveTable)
    parameters.Add("typeroute")
    Try
        Result = CType(gp.Execute("disolveRoute", parameters, trac), ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2)
    Catch ex As COMException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode)
    End Try

End Sub
```

For the inpute feature for disolve --> featureLayerRoute :

```
  Dim Sp As IWorkspace = ConnectToTransactionalVersion("localhost", "sde:postgresql:localhost", "sde", "....", "....")
        featureLayerRoute.FeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("piste_route")
        Dim layerrouteAs ILayer = featureLayerDroit
        layerroute.Name = featureLayerRoute.FeatureClass.AliasName
```

but when i execute this function it returned a Code ERROR -2147467259.. Please it's one Week i'm looking to solve it but Nothing :'(

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Comment: You won't get the detailed error unless you listen to the GP Messages. Additionally, in .NET you should always use the Geoprocessor Class, and not the IGeoProcessor interface. See : http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_get_returned_messages/000100000424000000/

Comment: Have a look at the code in this sample: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Executing_geoprocessing_tools/000100000161000000/

Comment: I Got this ERROR : Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Class.
Failed to execute (disolveRoute).

Comment: @Mounaim TAOUSSI Is the parameter's order valid?

Comment: yes @Darksanta but i solved the problem i will add the solution now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is :

1. the new Model is like :

[image: Model disolveRoute]

2. it Paramters like :

[image: parameters for the Model]

3. the Code :

---

```
  Sub diso()

        Dim gp As GeoProcessor = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessor()
        Dim trac As ITrackCancel = New CancelTracker
        Dim Result As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2
        Dim parameters As IVariantArray = New VarArrayClass()

        gp.OverwriteOutput = True
        gp.AddToolbox("data\Models.tbx")
        Dim featureWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace = CType(Sp, IFeatureWorkspace)
        Dim featureClass As IFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("piste_route")
        'Dim dissolveTable As IDataset = CType(featureClass, IDataset)
        parameters.Add(featureClass)
        parameters.Add("typeroute")
        parameters.Add("C:\Users\Mounaim\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog\IFE connexion.sde\sde.sde.unionPExec")
        Try
            Result = CType(gp.Execute("disolveRoute", parameters, trac), ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ExamplePrintGPErrorMessages(gp)
        End Try

    End Sub





 Public Sub ExamplePrintGPErrorMessages(ByVal gp As GeoProcessor)

        Dim sev As Object = 2
        Dim messages As String = gp.GetMessages(sev)
        System.Console.WriteLine(messages)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Are the reference as"
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
' Add references to esriSystem for licensing and IVariantArray.
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem
' Add a reference to the geoprocessing namespace.
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing
'Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor
"